# Create Magento 2 Bundles with different quantities of the same product

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, bundle, option

I'm currently running Magento 2.3.2. The Company I work for sells a number of products in bundles of varying quantities which we call "Stacks".

For example a product can be sold in bundles of either 1, 3 or 6. The price drops more as the customer orders a larger "stack".

The problem is that I can only seem to add the product once in each option, I really need it in the same option several times at different quantities.

I assume that there are probably extensions out there that can help with customizing bundle options but it really seems like this is should be a standard feature so I wondered if there was a way to do this "out of the box" as it were.

Can anyone suggest how to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, I think that the way to accomplish this in Magento 2 is to set tier prices on the products that are bundle items: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html (The customer group prices and tier prices from M1 are combined in M2 in a way that seems confusing.)

By doing this, the product only needs to be added once to a bundle item with the "User Defined" (quantity) checked.

I tested this on 2.3.2 and noticed that when the quantity is configured on the Bundle Product page, the tier price is not reflected. However, the lower price is applied in the cart.

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much does what I need it to do. Much obliged.